# Lyrics of the verses from Henrik Zeabird’s "Rain"

Tags: lyrics, henrik-zeabird

I can’t hear many parts from Henrik Zeabird’s *Rain* (available for download from [their Bandcamp page](http://henrikzeabird.bandcamp.com/)), and I can’t find the lyrics online (public lyrics sites, like LyricWikia, don’t list any songs from Henrik Zeabird, and searching for some phrases I do hear gives no results).

I think I hear the chorus (1:18–1:40, 2:21–2:44, 4:11–4:34), but have problems with the three verses.

My transcription attempt for the first verse (0:15–1:17):

> (The?) rain … falls outside
>   it’s …
>   it rains and rains and rains
>   cities and …
>   let’s push the sun away
>   we need more clouds
>   ’cause we want the water to rise on
>   The water starts to swell, make … smaller …
>   but pretty soon it’s growing more and more
>   … get bigger, yes it’s almost done
>   and (knew?) we can swim

Based on this is the last verse (3:39–4:09):

> The rain still falls outside, it’s …
>   it rains and rains and rains, … and …
>   let’s push the sun away
>   ’cause we want more clouds
>   we (want?) the water to rise on

And the second verse (1:49–2:19):

> The house is (past?) …  boat
>   I’ve never seen them small like this
>   I‘ve never seen my city … from that point of view
>   and I like the world much better than before

The parts I can’t hear are marked with `…`, the parts I’m unsure about are enclosed in `( ?)`, but even the parts I transcribed don’t have to be correct, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

> It rains, it falls outside 
>    it's without end
>    it rains and rains and rains
>     it is endless
>   let’s push the sun away
>    we need more clouds
>   ’cause we want the water to rise on
>    The water starts to swell, it builds smaller lakes
>   but pretty soon it’s growing more and more
>   the lakes get bigger, yes it’s almost done
>    and, ooooooo, we can swim

V2:

> The houses pass us by as we sit on our boat
>   I’ve never seen them small like this
>   I‘ve never seen my city from that point of view
>   and I like the world much better than before

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be spot on :) Although I can never hear the "k" in "lakes" (wonder if it’s her pronounciation or my hearing?), it totally makes sense. -- Between "I‘ve never seen my city" and "from that point of view" there is *something* … probably just an "ooo" or so, I guess.

Comment: The *a* sound in 'city-*a*-from' sounds to me like she's just neglecting to stop singing in the gap between those words (maybe deliberately). Similarly, "smaller lakes" might be "small-*a*-lakes" - i.e. just "small lakes" - which would make more sense, though lots of the grammar and pronunciation is a bit quirky. Of course someone might come along and clear up what *I'm* mishearing!